# Specify argument in python

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I am trying to use scipy.sparse.linalg.spilu(http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.spilu.html#scipy.sparse.linalg.spilu), I want to specify milu=silu.

If my function call is : `M=spla.spilu(A=A, milu=silu)`
It gave me error looks like below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bicgstab_python.py", line 13, in <module>
    M=spla.spilu(A=A, milu=silu)
NameError: name 'silu' is not defined
```

If my function call is:  `M=spla.spilu(A=A, milu='silu')`
It gave me error looks like below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bicgstab_python.py", line 13, in <module>
    M=spla.spilu(A=A, milu='silu')
TypeError: spilu() got an unexpected keyword argument 'milu'
```

I would like to know I should I correctly specify parameter milu in this function? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to provide parameter A without keyword A? M=spla.spilu(A, milu='silu')

Comment: What version of scipy are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second way you used is the right way to specify the argument.

However, according to the latest version of scipy source code:https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.15.1/scipy/sparse/linalg/dsolve/linsolve.py, there is no "milu" argument in the spilu function though it still appears in the comments. So I guess this is a legacy argument which is no longer supported and you should not use it in your code.